# not able to include jquery 1-4.4 in jsp's

Tags: jquery, jsp

i am using jquery version 1-4.4 in my jsp page.

following alert box appear in my Internet explorer.
[image]

[image]

this is my jsp page code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            alert("Thanks for visiting!");
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("jquery version 1.4.4");
    });
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
</body>
</html>
```

but the same cod runing with jquery version 1.3.2.

why it is not working with version 1.4.4?
even it is not working with the jquery 1.3.2 greater version.

help me out!

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: no error on console. i am using tomcat 7 version.

Comment: ok Nishant, this will solve my problem. but when i put jquery1-4.4 file in my web folder it is not including. why this happening.?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file is accesible by visiting the js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js in your browser.

If it is not then simply updating the file's permissions is all you will probably need to do.